# How to find missing number from different ranges

Tags: postgresql, query, sequence

I have a table with two columns, one containing name and other numbers. For each name there is range of numbers and there are around 250 names in there. Range of every name is different. It may be 1 to 10 or 1 to 100 or 1 to 150.

There are missing numbers in the range of each name. I need to find out the missing numbers against each name. How can it be done?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Feeling in the mood for riddles, my guess at the missing table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE item (
  item_name text PRIMARY KEY
, nr_range  int NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE item_nr (
  item_name text NOT NULL REFERENCES item
, nr        int NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (item_name, nr)   
);
```

Then the query can be:

```
SELECT i.*, n.nr
FROM   item i
CROSS  JOIN generate_series(1, i.nr_range) n(nr)
LEFT   JOIN item_nr x USING (item_name, nr)
WHERE  i.item_name = 'foo'
AND    x.nr IS NULL;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/M3-JSZXd)

Comment: I'll add explanation after you have clarified the question.